# jquery innerwidth in IE7 is off

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-7

I am trying to get the width of parent div using jquery.innerwidth() which is not working correctly for IE7.

Create fiddle [here.](http://jsfiddle.net/dkindler/6SLbn/) which actually looks okay in fiddle but not in IE7 which I do not understand either.

I am using jquery v1.4.2

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/dan_barzilay/6SLbn/1/

i used .width() instad of .innerWidth() and the paramaters for the css function were wrong.